# Slack API upload snippet length

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

My snippets are truncated to a few hundred lines. This is the code I'm using to upload them

```
 self.client.api_call(
     'files.upload',
     channels=channel_id,
     content=msg,
     as_user='true:',
     filetype=filetype,
     filename=filename
 )
```

What other parameter do I need to set to allow posting the entire snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any. This limitation is imposed by Slack API for `files.upload` method.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload):

> There is a 1 megabyte file size limit for files uploaded as snippets.